# How to destroy resources created using terraform in azure devops pipeline by using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines

I have a project where I'm using Terraform in Azure DevOps Pipeline create Infrastructure but want to destroy the infrastructure in a PowerShell script running locally.

So the PScommand that I want to run is this:

```
$TerraCMD = "terraform destroy -var-file C:/Users/Documents/Terraform/config.json"

Invoke-Expression -Command $TerraCMD
```

But I get the following output:

```
[0m[1m[32mNo changes.[0m[1m No objects need to be destroyed.[0m

[0mEither you have not created any objects yet or the existing objects were
already deleted outside of Terraform.
[33mâ•·[0m[0m
[33mâ”‚[0m [0m[1m[33mWarning: [0m[0m[1mValue for undeclared variable[0m
[33mâ”‚[0m [0m
[33mâ”‚[0m [0m[0mThe root module does not declare a variable named "config" but a value was
[33mâ”‚[0m [0mfound in file
[33mâ”‚[0m [0m"C:/Users/mahera.erum.baloch/source/repos/PCFA-CloudMigration/On-Prem-Env/IaC/Terraform/config.json".
[33mâ”‚[0m [0mIf you meant to use this value, add a "variable" block to the
[33mâ”‚[0m [0mconfiguration.
[33mâ”‚[0m [0m
[33mâ”‚[0m [0mTo silence these warnings, use TF_VAR_... environment variables to provide
[33mâ”‚[0m [0mcertain "global" settings to all configurations in your organization. To
[33mâ”‚[0m [0mreduce the verbosity of these warnings, use the -compact-warnings option.
[33mâ•µ[0m[0m
[0m[1m[32m
Destroy complete! Resources: 0 destroyed.
```

I know this is probably due to that I created the resources through the pipeline and not from local repository, but is there a way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. The State file is saved in the Azure Storage.

Comment: Since you are running your Terraform commands in a pipeline can you tell us where your state is saved? Is it local or in something like an S3 bucket or Azure storage?

If it's local you need to add a backend provider so you have your state saved externally.

Comment: @Zucchini ok so the state is saved in the Azure Storage

Comment: The warning implies this is not being executed in the correct directory.

Comment: unless it's in the same task that you created the resources, pretty sure you need to do `terraform init` with all the same parameters that you used in the task when you created it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that your code is kept in a repo that you have access to, since you mentioned that it's being deployed from Terraform running in an Azure DevOps Pipeline.

As others mentioned, the state file AND your terraform code is your source of truth. Hence, you'd need for both the PowerShell script and the Pipeline to be referring to the same state file and code, to achieve what you're trying to.

For the `terraform destroy` to run, it would need access to both your Terraform code and the state file so that it can compare what needs to be destroyed.

Unless your setup is very different from this, you could have your PowerShell script just `git clone` or `git pull` the repo, depending on your requirements, and then execute a `terraform destroy` on that version of the code. Your state file will then be updated accordingly.

Comment: I already have the same repo cloned on my local so why do I have to clone it again? The state file is stored in a storage account in Azure. Can you give an example how can this be achieved?

Comment: If you have your repo cloned locally then there's not much else you need to do. It seems you have the right setup but there could be something else happening to your code/resources. After you deploy the resources from your pipeline, try to inspect the state file locally to see if you're able to view the terraform objects and also compare with the resources that exist in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into the problem of keeping Terraform state from an Azure Pipeline build.  Repeated builds of the pipeline fail because the resource group already exists, but the Terraform state is not kept by the build pipeline.  And I can find no way to execute `terraform destroy` on the pipeline even if I had the state.

One approach I found in chapter 2 of [this book](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-devops/9781801818964/) is storing terraform.tfstate in a remote back end.  This looks like it will keep .tfstate across multiple builds of the pipeline and from elsewhere too.

I don't know yet if it will allow a `terraform destroy`.